# Command-line REST client in Java with parameters?

Tags: java, rest, client

I am using this Java REST client (version 2.3):

> http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

I am trying to run it from the command line:

```
java -jar <REST_CLIENT.JAR> <login> <password> PUT http://bsmgw.bms.consulting.com/opr-console/rest/9.10/event_list/6eea76ae-ff22-71e0-0431-ac10016b0000 update2.xm`l
```

For example:

```
C:\test\REST>java -jar restclient-cli-2.3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar -o C:\test\REST\ output3.rcq
Starting: C:\test\REST\output3.rcq
org.wiztools.restclient.XMLException
            at org.wiztools.restclient.XMLUtil.response2XML(XMLUtil.java:433)
            at org.wiztools.restclient.XMLUtil.writeResponseXML(XMLUtil.java:571)
            at org.wiztools.restclient.cli.CliMain$CliView.doResponse(CliMain.java:75)
            at org.wiztools.restclient.HTTPClientRequestExecuter.execute(HTTPClientRequestExecuter.java:387)
            at org.wiztools.restclient.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.wiztools.restclient.XMLUtil.response2XML(XMLUtil.java:406)
            ... 4 more
End: C:\test\REST\output3.rcq
```

`Total tests executed: 1
Total failures:       1
Total errors:         0`

This works fine in the GUI version, why doesn't it work from the command line?

Comment: This might be the problem: _No read access: C:\test\REST\org.wiztools.restclient.CliMain_

Comment: Seems like an egregious number of downvotes on this question. @ostapv - check that your (oddly) named input file is actually readable by the user you are running the process under.

Comment: Run under administrator,                                                      C:\test\REST>java -jar restclient-cli-2.3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.wiztools.restclient.CliMain -o C:\test\REST
No read access: C:\test\REST\org.wiztools.restclient.CliMain

Answer (score 0):

The format is:

```
java -jar <JAR> org.wiztools.restclient.CliMain -o <output dir> <input request files>
```

While you've provided `-o C:\test\REST\ output.rcq`, which means it'll check output.rcq for inputs. Are you really storing the input requests in a file called `output.rcq` or is that your problem? From the stack trace it looks like that file is empty.

Comment: Input request file empty)), I dont know what set in file http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

Comment: You need to go back and reformulate your question. If you don't know what to put in the file, then say that rather than... I honestly don't know what you're trying to say in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I found examples .crq files

Comment: You have to first record the request using the REST Client UI and save the request. After saving the request, you will be able to execute the saved request from command-line.